# Add a eps picture

Tags: graphics, eps

Recently,I want to add a picture:

My code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\[   
    \begin{bmatrix}
        a_{11} & b_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
        a_{21} & b_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n} \\
        \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
        a_{i1} & b_{i2} & \cdots & a_{in} \\
        \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
        b_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & b_{ns}
        \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
    b_{1}  \\
    b_{2} \\
    \vdots \\
    b_{i} \\
    \vdots \\
    b_{n} 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    c_{1}  \\
    c_{2} \\
    \vdots \\
    c_{i} \\
    \vdots \\
    c_{n} 
   \end{bmatrix}
  \]

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{31} \\ 
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{32} \\ 
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\ 
a_{42} & a_{42} & a_{43}
\end{bmatrix} 
\]

\includegraphics{pic.eps}

\end{document}
```

However, it shows `! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .eps.`

So my question is how to revise it?

Comment: Or try to omit the `.eps` extension, like `\includegraphics{pic}`

Comment: Adding the *additional processing* mentioned by barbara: package `epstopdf`. Well, @barbara comment went missing, so again: You cannot include eps files with pdflatex by default.

Comment: @marczellm,Thanks,but it donot works

Comment: @Johannes_B ,+1:)Thanks sincerely,perfect!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it work if you use `epstopdf` package by including `\usepackage{epstopdf}` in your preamble?